Как правильно сделать отправку картинок через callback в aiogram 3.x?
У меня есть код, который генерирует картинки
После чего они сохраняются у меня локально в папку, имя каждой картинки = callback_data.png, имя папки =uid, введенный юзером
Затем создаются кнопки, каждая из которых именуется своим именем, взятым из
словаря, который парсится с сайта (Имя картинки это key, имя кнопки это value).
callback_data каждой картинки соответствует своему key из словаря (от 1 до 8 картинок)
Пробовал через FSM перекидывать в callback переменную uid, благодаря чему всё работает как надо (выдает юзеру картинку), но уходит в рекурсию из-за того, что я не очищаю FSM state.clear(). А если я очищаю, то у меня перестает работать callback, т.к. не получает переменную uid. В итоге бот ломается, постоянно повторяя функцию character_card
Пробовал через sqlite заносить tg id и uid (который пишет юзер в чат), но оттуда в переменную не достать
Мне надо каким-то образом заставить работать callback по моей задумке, чтобы он выдавал конкретному юзеру конкретную картинку из конкретной папки по callback
Тут в основной код бота засунуты все функции для примера, чтоб понятно было что откуда куда
def get_some_kb(some_dict: dict) -> InlineKeyboardMarkup:
                kb = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
                for key, value in some_dict.items():
                    kb.button(text=value, 
                    callback_data=f"{key}", 
                    )
                kb.adjust(2)
                return kb.as_markup() 

class Reg(StatesGroup):
name = State()
name1 = State()
name2 = State()


router = Router()


@router.message(Command('character'),
                 StateFilter(None)
)
async def enkanet(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Reg.name)
    await message.answer('Напиши свой UID')
    print("card request")
    

    
@router.message(
        StateFilter(Reg.name)
)
async def character_card(message: Message,
                           state: FSMContext,
) -> None:  # noqa: C901, D103
    await state.update_data(name=message.text)
    data = await state.get_data()    
    uid = data["name"]
    tgid = message.from_user.id
    cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (uid, tg_id) VALUES (({uid}), ({tgid}))")
    db.commit()
    await message.bot.send_chat_action(
    chat_id=message.chat.id,
    action=ChatAction.TYPING
    )
    
    async with starrailcard.Card(save=True, remove_logo=True) as card: #Генератор картинок
        try:
            await message.answer("ЖДИ\n\n\nСекунд 10~15")
            await card.set_lang("ru")
            data1 = await card.create(uid=uid, style=2, force_update=True)
            result = errorz()
            if result:
                print("Something went WRONG")
                return message.answer("Что-то пошло не так... Введите UID снова")
            key_id = data1.get_charter()
            kb = get_some_kb(key_id) 
        except StarRailCardError:    
            print("StarRailCardError")
            return message.answer("Что-то пошло не так... Введите UID")    
    await message.answer(f"{uid}\n\nВыберите...", reply_markup=kb)




@router.callback_query()
async def send_generated_image(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    await state.update_data(name=message.text)
    data = await state.get_data()    
    uid = data["name"]
    photo_file = FSInputFile(path=f"E:/papka/{uid}/{call.data}.png") #Здесь у каждого uid своя папка
    await call.message.answer_photo(photo=photo_file)

Решил таким образом, всё работает по задумке, НО теперь проблема, что работает только когда юзер один единственный. Надо как-то каждому tg_id привязать свой uid при выдаче картинки, но при этом оставить UPDATE . Я не знаю как это сделать
async def add(id, tgid):
    info = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE tg_id=?', (tgid, )).fetchone()
    if info is None: 
        cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (uid, tg_id) VALUES (({id}), ({tgid}))")
        db.commit() 
    else:
        sqlite_update_query = f"""UPDATE users SET uid = {id} WHERE tg_id = {tgid}"""
        cur.execute(sqlite_update_query)
        db.commit()
        if sq.OperationalError:
            return
        return 

 @router.message(
            StateFilter(Reg.name)
    )
    async def character_card(message: Message,
                               state: FSMContext,
    ) -> None:  
        await state.update_data(name=message.text)
        data = await state.get_data()    
        id = data["name"]
        tgid = message.from_user.id
        await tg.add(id=id, tgid=tgid)
    #тут далее идет генерация картинки и отправка кнопок

  

     @router.callback_query() #проблема вот здесь с рассинхроном tg_id и uid
        async def send_generated_image(call: CallbackQuery):
            uid = cur.execute("SELECT uid FROM users").fetchone()[0]
            tgid1 = cur.execute("SELECT tg_id FROM users").fetchone()[0]
            print(uid, tgid1)
            path = 'E:/papka/' + f"{uid}/{call.data}" + '.png'
            photo_file = FSInputFile(path=path)
            await call.message.answer_photo(photo=photo_file)


ЕСЛИ ЧТО, заранее извиняюсь, если ответ прям супер очевиден для кого-то и спасибо за любой отклик на вопрос
